# Is it possible to combine magics in IPython / Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Sometimes you want to use several magics at the same time. Now I know you can use

```
%%time
%%bash
ls
```

But when I make my own commands this chaining doesn't work...

```
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic

@register_cell_magic
def accio(line, cell):
    print('accio')
    exec(cell)
```

results in an error when using

```
%%accio
%%bash
ls
```

What should I use rather than `exec`?

Comment: `%%time` magic use `exec` internally too, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing :) just that it doesn't seem to be able to chain :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to apply the IPython special transformations, to run the nested magic with the cell, [like the `%%time` magic](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L1138-L1251):

```
@register_cell_magic
def accio(line, cell):
    ipy = get_ipython()
    expr = ipy.input_transformer_manager.transform_cell(cell)
    expr_ast = ipy.compile.ast_parse(expr)
    expr_ast = ipy.transform_ast(expr_ast)
    code = ipy.compile(expr_ast, '', 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

or simply call `run_cell`:

```
@register_cell_magic
def accio(line, cell):
    get_ipython().run_cell(cell)
```

result:

```
In [1]: %%accio
   ...: %%time
   ...: %%bash
   ...: date
   ...:
accio
Wed Nov 14 17:41:55 CST 2018
CPU times: user 1.42 ms, sys: 4.21 ms, total: 5.63 ms
Wall time: 9.64 ms
```

Comment: This looks great :) Going to check in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In IPython source code, they almost always use a class for creating magic statements because they can hold values, and I think that's what your looking for.

Check this source code to see some [examples](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/).